# How to keep UITableView centered on X and Y inside an UIStackView

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

I have an `UILabel` and a `UITableView` inside an vertical `UIStackView`. I want this stack view to always remain centered, even when elements are added to the table view.

Right now I added a `Horizontal in Container` and `Vertical in Container` constraints to the stack view. But it still says that the stack view is missing a Y constraint. If I add one then it won't be centered anymore.

Any idea what constraints should I add to keep it always centered ?

Here are two screen shots with how I want my stack view and one with what I have now:

[image]

[image]

The second picture I added a vertical space constraint from stack view to title that's why it looks like that.

Comment: You'll probably have to fiddle with orientation and spacing settings in the stack view to get what you're after. One thing to remember with stack views is you can rarely get it to look 100% the way you want it to. You get more ease with stack views but much more control with hard constraints IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mmm... I had this very same request from a client some time ago and the thing is that table views are not meant to be used like that because if you add too many items the table is going to grow in both vertical directions and thats not good at all... BUT! as far as I can see, your cells are all the same size so, this is what I did as my table had a few and finite number of rows and all of them were the same size:

I added a height constraint to the tableView and throw it as an IBOutlet to the class it belongs to. Once you have the number of rows for your tasks, you can just update the constant value for the tableView height constraint you have by multiplying the number of rows for the fixed height of your cells. That way your tableView will have a height defined by the number of rows it contains. You should probably just dump the stack view, use the tableView by itself and add some size and centering constraints to your tableView having into  account this height constraint I mentioned... Specifically:

Leading/Trailing or Width as you prefer, vertically centered inside container and the height constraint you are going to modify on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

By the way I'm looking at it **your stackview is occupying the whole screen**, I feel you should go with the normal constraints leading to container, trailing to container, bottom space to container, top space to vertical.

Think about it for a second, if you add these four constraints, your stack view will still be always horizontally and vertically centered, no matter on which device you run it on, because settings these 4 constraints will always ensure the stackview maintains that constant distance from the superview margins which in your case would be 0 for all the constraints

Comment: I added leading, trailing and top constraint to title and bottom constraint to button, but all of the contents are at top, not middle. My stack view alignment and distribution are set to Fill.

Comment: Set them to fill equally and adjust your custom spacing

Comment: But if I do that, the gap between the label and table view is too big, because it tries to make the label the same size as the table view, right ?

Comment: Correct, try adding width and height constraints on label and then insert in the stackview

Comment: I did that, but apparently the stackview shrinks down, and the title at the top is increased, because of the constraint to it. I try playing with the hugging content properties but still same issue. the title now occupies more than half the screen, while the stackview is down the bottom.

Comment: Let me open xcode and do some stuff on my own, think can figure it out by playing with it